# How does Angular 2 CLI load plugins for build (for instance for the mobile-toolkit)

Tags: angular, angular2-cli

In former versions the CLI had a huge broccoli configuration file. Using this, one was able to define - for instance - how the CLI had to create a build. As this file is gone now, I'm wondering how the CLI knows what to do when ng build is called.

For instance, it uses the packages @angular/service-worker and @angular/app-shell if it's there.

Wishes,
Manfred